# Getters return null in Angular Factory methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables

I have the following factory and when I call the setters, from controller function, it sets the name but if I call the getters from controller, it returns null. Why the variables values are not showing up?

```css
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .factory('myFactory', ServiceFactory);

    myFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$rootScope'];
    var config = {
        // TO DO : check if anything required
    };
 
 

    /* @ngInject */
    function myFactory($http, $rootScope) {
 
 var userName = null;
 var userId = null;
 var pwd = null;
 
 var service = {
            
            getUserName: getUserName,
            setUserName: setUserName,
   getPwd:getPwd,
            setPwd:setPwd,
          
        };
  function getUserName() {
            console.log("user name.getUserName." + userName);
            return userName;
        }

        function setUserName(userName) {
            console.log("user name.." + userName);
            userName = userName;
        }

       
        function getPwd() {
            console.log("user getPwd.." + pwd);
            return pwd;
        }

        function setPwd(pwd) {
            console.log("user setPwd.." + pwd);
            pwd = pwd;
        }
  
  return service;
 }
})();
```

Comment: Show us your controller code. Pls

Comment: `ServiceFactory` in this case should be replaced by `myFactory`, no?

Comment: yes..its myFactory

Comment: Can you try this? this.pwd = pwd; & return this.pwd;

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to understand javascript lexical scoping. Go through javascript lexical scoping. And below is the rectified code.

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <title>Fixed :Getters return null in Angular Factory methods</title>
</head>
<body class="debug" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    {{name}}
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function () {
            'use strict';

            var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

            app.factory('myFactory', myFactory);

            myFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$rootScope'];
            var config = {
                // TO DO : check if anything required
            };


            /* @ngInject */
            function myFactory($http, $rootScope) {

                var userName = null; //global
                var userId = null;   //global
                var pwd = null;     //global

                var service = {
                    getUserName: getUserName,
                    setUserName: setUserName,
                    getPwd:getPwd,
                    setPwd:setPwd,
                };
                function getUserName() {
                    console.log("user name.getUserName." + userName);
                    return userName;
                }

                function setUserName(name) { //userName -> local variable
                    console.log("user name.." + name);
                   // userName = userName; //You thing the leftside "userName" is global but its referencing to localvariable. So give it a differnt name. Cheking variable scope in javascript.
                    userName = name;
                }


                function getPwd() {
                    console.log("user getPwd.." + pwd);
                    return pwd;
                }

                function setPwd(password) {  //pwd -> local variable
                    console.log("user setPwd.." + password);
                    //pwd = pwd; //You thing the leftside "pwd" is global but its referencing to local variable. So give a differnt name. Cheking variable scope in javascript.
                    pwd = password;
                }

                return service;
            }

            app.controller('mainCtrl',mainCtrlFn);

            mainCtrlFn.$inject = ['$scope','myFactory'];

            function mainCtrlFn($scope,myFactory) {
                myFactory.setUserName("Sai Ram");
                $scope.name = myFactory.getUserName();
            }
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```